# Is it planned to implement Hashed Timelocked Contracts (HTLC) through the monero multisig wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, multisig

In other words, will be  there equivalent of the command 'locked_transfer' for sending funds to multisig wallet? 
So a sender can return the funds by using just his signature (ONLY through the 'number of block to lock').

It will be necessary for implementation of HTLC, cross-chain atomic swap and returning erroneously blocked  funds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that's planned just yet. In any case, Monero's time lock implementation is incompatible with that of Bitcoin-based currencies, so right now atomic swaps between Monero and, say, Bitcoin wouldn't work. At least a modification to the atomic swap protocol would be needed. https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1184